# Test email sends

Tags: marketing-cloud

It appears that when I send a test email from Marketing Cloud I can only send it to one recipient. I've tried comma separated addresses. I feel like there must be a way to send to multiple people, am I being an idiot?
How can I send a test email to a list of email addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to send to multiple recipients is to create a test list within the Marketing Cloud that holds all addresses for your testing group, then use the Simple send to choose that list.

If you are using the classic email test sends, the email addresses default to just you, but you should be able to add other recipients in the next spaces.
How to from Classic Email Studio: From the desired email, click Send -> Test Send, this opens a Modal window with your email showing and three more empty fields, type the email of your intended recipients here, one to each field (note: the recipients must be on the subscriber list within MC somewhere, or you will be asked to add them), click send.

hope that helps.
Pam

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable with User-Initiated Sends and Data Extensions, then you might prefer this method.  This process assumes you already have a User-Initiated Send and data extension configures for your production email.

First, make a copy of the data extension used for the production email. Import your test records into the new data extension. Edit the properties of the data extension by checking the flag **"User for testing"**.  This property is on the same screen where you would make a data extension sendable.

Next, edit the corresponding User-Initiated Send for the production email. Add the newly created data extension to the **Test Audience** section.  Save the configuration.

Now, when you place a check mark on the User-Initiated Send, the **Test Send** button becomes active. Click the **Test Send** button.  On this new screen, review the setting and click the **Test Send** button again.

*Note:  On this last screen, you have the option to specify a different emails in the **send all emails to** section.  This will send the personalized email for each member in the test audience to a single emailaddress.  This is a great way for testing dynamic elements in an email.*